# Underscore character matched all the email address regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have my email adress format like **username@domain.extension**

- The username starts with an English alphabetical character, and any subsequent characters consist of one or more of the following: alphanumeric characters, **-, . , and _.**
- The domain and extension contain only English alphabetical characters.
  The extension is 1,2 or 3 characters in length.

I have used the below regex to validate my email address:

```
[a-zA-Z]+\s<\b[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,3}\b>
```

Email adresses:

```
this <is@valid.com>
this <is_it@valid.com>
this <_is@notvalid.com>
this <.is@notvalid.com>
this <-is@notvalid.com>
```

It matched email address 1,2,3  while 4,5 have . and - at the start of domain so it got rejected. So why for 3rd email underscore at the starting of domain it's causing issue and getting accepted.I can't have **. , - , _** at the start of domain as per instructions mentioned above. Here is the [link](https://regex101.com/r/hm4nxU/1)

***Correct ans:***
1,2 email should only match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character class after `<\b` is accepting `_` hence any email address starting with `-` is also becoming valid.

You can use this regex to only allow an alphabet as starting letter of your email:

```
[a-zA-Z]+\s<\b[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*@[a-zA-Z]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,3}\b>
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hm4nxU/2)

or you can make use of `\w`:

```
[a-zA-Z]+\s<\b[a-zA-Z][\w.-]*@[a-zA-Z]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,3}\b>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution .Why  we need to use to use [a-zA-Z0-9._-] separately ? @anubhava

Comment: Because `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+` will also allow `_` as first character. To avoid it have `[a-zA-Z]` as first character and then have `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*` to match 2nd position onwards.

Comment: ok.seems like underscore has some different meaning because if i give like [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+ **(Without underscore)** it will not match the string,so email would be rejected

Comment: I mean if you have .,- at start of domain like **.is@notvalid.com** it rejects email with my condition [a-zA-Z0-9._-]+ but that didn't happened with underscore at starting. so i thought i has some different meaning and we including it in separate class.

Comment: Oh it is rejecting it because of `\b` just after `<`. `\b` asserts true before a word character only. Note that `_` is a word character but dot is not.

Answer (score 1):

Newbie to regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]+[ ][<][a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z._-]+[@][a-zA-Z]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,3})[>]
```

It's my try for your problem:
   [image]

Comment: No it just passed for that particular case. Not sure why use using extra square brackets for <,>

Comment: With square brackets, there is any problem or any other thing happen?